# Can you call two promises from inside the same controller?

Tags: javascript, express

This is the error message I am receiving when I go to route `/signup/confirm/:id`

> **Error:** Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
>       at new ObjectID (C:\Users\royalBishop101\Desktop\Projects\node-blog\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\objectid.js:59:11)
>       at Function.findById (C:\Users\royalBishop101\Desktop\Projects\node-blog\model\signups.js:32:51)

Here's my controller code:

```js
exports.confirm = (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    Signups.findById(id)
        .then(data => {
            newUser = new User(data.username, data.password, data.name);
            newUser.save()
                .then(() => {
                    Signups.deleteSignup(id)
                        .then(() => {
                            res.redirect('admin');
                        })
                        .catch(err => console.log(err));
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Here's my Model Code:

```js
class Signups {
    constructor(name, password, username) {
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
        this.username = username;
    }

    static findById(id) {
        const db = getDb();
        return db.collection('signup').find({
            _id: new mongodb.ObjectId(id)
        }).next();
    }

    static deleteSignup(id) {
        const db = getDb();
        return db.collection('signup').deleteOne({
            _id: new mongodb.ObjectId(id)
        });
    }
}
```

If I comment out either step 1 or step 2 and run the code it will work and not throw that error, but if I uncomment one of them where they both will run then I get the error.

So I know its not an error in my `findbyId` method in my model like the error says. Not sure whats going on.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you tried logging the value and typeof of `id`? Exactly what URL are you hitting?

Comment: Yeah, the correct id is logged when I console.log the value. I just logged the typeof id and its a string. The exact URL is localhost:3000/signup/confirm/5e34c09a3d089d266c4d155f

Comment: Can you post the `deleteSignup` method?

Comment: Whenever I check mongo Atlas the database operations are being performed even though that error is crashing my app; it looks up the correct signup document and then creates and saves a new user document in the users collection and deletes the signup document from the signup collection.

Comment: does `newUser.save();` return a promise?

Comment: static deleteSignup(id) {
        const db = getDb();
        return db.collection('signup').deleteOne({_id: new mongodb.ObjectId(id)});
    }

Comment: code needs to go in question - you can edit your question

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest let me check the mongo docs and see if insertOne() returns a promise.

Comment: I think that save() returns a promise. If that's the case, that's where the deleteSignup should be placed.

Comment: I moved the deleteSignup method inside .then block for the save method and I am receiving the same error.

Comment: I found what was causing the error. It surprisingly had to do with the routes. Instead of using an anchor tag and making a GET request I changed it to a form and made a POST request and that stopped the error. Still not 100% sure what the issue was though. I'm chalking it up to routes interfering somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only one reason why your `objectId` is correct but you got some message like that is because white space in your id:

Make sure use `trim()` to remove all white space. You can do it like this code below:

```js
class Signups {
    constructor(name, password, username) {
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
        this.username = username;
    }

    static findById(id) { 
        console.log('Before: Find');
        console.log(id);
        console.log(id.length);
        id = id.trim();
        console.log('After: Find');
        console.log(id);
        console.log(id.length);
        const db = getDb();
        return db.collection('signup').find({_id: new mongodb.ObjectId(id) }).next();
    }

    static deleteSignup(id) { 
         console.log('Before: Delete');
         console.log(id);
         console.log(id.length);
         id = id.trim();
         console.log('After: Delete');
         console.log(id);
         console.log(id.length);
         const db = getDb();
         return db.collection('signup').deleteOne({_id: new mongodb.ObjectId(id)}); 
     }

}
```

Now, you can try again and I hope it's work.

I hope it can help you.